# Laravel - Customize the key in the route model binding with json field

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to customize the key in the route model binding and i do something like this -

```
use App\Models\Post;

Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', function (Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

But my slug is a json multilingual field and holds data like this -

```
{
  'en': 'hello'
  'ru': 'привет',
  'de': 'hallo',
}
```

I already have a mechanism to retrieve the subdomain and assign the corresponding prefix to some $subdomain variable, so i already know which language i should grab from the DB, but how do i embed this $subdomain inside the route itself? Something like -

```
Route::get('/posts/{post:slug->$subdomain}', function (Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

I even tried to put the whole route into a pre-defined string with something like this -

```
$post_url = '/posts/{post:slug->'.$subdomain.'}';
Route::get($post_url, function (Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

And it also resulted in constant 404 errors.
What am I doing wrong?

- Needless to say that it works perfectly when simply retrieving posts by their IDs, and even with non-multilingual slugs. The problem starts with these JSON fields.

Comment: You'll probably need to write your custom logic in the [RouteServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic).

Comment: thanks. i was just about to respond to myself that this is what i eventually did - `Route::bind('post', function ($value) { 
            $slug = "slug->".$subdomain;
            return Post::where($slug, $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
        });`

Comment: Glad you found a solution. When you can, post it as an answer for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to explicitly bind this route inside the `RouteServiceProvide.php` like this -

```
Route::bind('post', function ($value) {
            $slug = "slug->".$subdomain;
                return Post::where($slug, $value)->firstOrFail();
        });
```

Then I could easily access any language version of the post.

Comment: Thanks for this solution i was facing the same issue.